# How to put the woocommerce order date in a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm trying to put the date of the order placed on woocommerce in a shortcode.

This is what I did:

```
add_shortcode( 'data-pagamento' , 'data_pgmnt' ); 
function data_pgmnt() { 
  $customer_id = get_current_user_id(); 
  $order = jet_woo_builder_template_functions()->get_current_received_order(); 
  $date_paid =  $order->get_date_paid();
  return $date_paid->date("j/m/Y");
}
```

In the past this works, now for some reason it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Actually the code works, I realized that it is the get_date_paid that breaks the layout. So I replaced it with get_date_created and changed it as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after several attempts. I found that I was formatting the code wrong, consequently I wrote like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'data-pagamento' , 'data_pgmnt' );
function data_pgmnt() {
    $customer_id = get_current_user_id();
    $order = jet_woo_builder_template_functions()->get_current_received_order();
    $date = $order->get_date_created()->format ('j/m/Y – g:i A');
    return $date;
}
```

I can now see the order date on the thank you page. I placed the code in the child theme's functions.php file.

get_date_paid breaks the page layout. I suppose this happens because I paid with paypal sandbox, so there is no actual payment date.

Reference: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/